# Building Multi-Module Maven Project in Different Dockerfiles

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile

I have a project of microservices that is multi-module and each module has several modules as follows:

```
+-- my-project
   +-- module1
   |   `-- pom.xml
       +-- module1.1
           `-- pom.xml
       +-- module1.2
           `-- pom.xml
       +-- module1.3
           `-- pom.xml
   +-- module2
   |   `-- pom.xml
       +-- module2.1
           `-- pom.xml
       +-- module2.2
           `-- pom.xml
       +-- module2.3
           `-- pom.xml
  `- pom.xml
```

And it's running by making each of the module-N import and organize the dependencies, but I want to make the main pom be the parent of them all, and it's working just fine(locally), the main issue is that the project runs on N DockerFiles for each submodule.
Here's an example of one of the DockerFiles:

```
###Build stage###
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17-slim AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY easymarine-movement/ /app
RUN mvn clean install

###Package stage###
FROM openjdk:17-slim
COPY --from=build /app/movement-application/target/movement-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/movement.jar
EXPOSE 8063
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/movement.jar","--spring.profiles.active=hmlg"]
```

So for each main module I have a Dockerfile to run It independently, so I can freely choose to build a specific one...
I tried passing the main pom.xml to the project like so:

```
###Build stage###
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17-slim AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml /app --here
COPY easymarine-movement/ /app
RUN mvn clean install

###Package stage###
FROM openjdk:17-slim
COPY --from=build /app/movement-application/target/movement-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/movement.jar
EXPOSE 8063
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/movement.jar","--spring.profiles.active=hmlg"]
```

But it's throwing an error at the `mvn clean install` that the other child modules does not exists, and I know that's correct but is there a way to work this around??